# How to run a Jenkins build only if another build has been successful?

Tags: jenkins

I want Jenkins to run a regularly scheduled build A **only** if another regularly scheduled build B has been successful. If the build A has failed the this way dependent build B should not run (since it would fail also). 
I don't want to trigger B from A directly since B as a completely other schedule (runs more infrequently).

Comment: Make Job A as a down stream job to Job B and trigger Job A only when  Job B is successful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [BuildResultTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin) - you can set it in job *B* to poll the results of job *A* with the desired (un)frequency.

Comment: Plugin works - but unfortunately it seems to be triggered only when the condition changes. So if I have a job on which I depend and which is always green my job is never triggered. Any more ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to trigger job _B_ remotely and let the job only run if job _A_ was successful? I was only able to set up a schedule for building.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).  As a post-build step on B, have job A be triggered on a successful build.  You don't have to specify parameters.

Comment: This is exactly what Strinder DIDN'T want... (how-come it got selected as the correct answer?)